# ag-grid cell editors - how to save data to backend

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Could you please help me with an example that shows saving data to backend service after editing 1/many cells in angular js? I found examples on how to write a custom cell editor and use ag grid's default cell editors but could not find how and where to plug in my code that saves edits to backend services?

Comment: Just to check are you using AngularJS? Or Angular 2-8?

Comment: I am using Angular 6

Comment: Ahh, ok. I was confusef for a moment because you mentioned AngularJS

Comment: Do you want to send the entire data grid to the backend? Or just the ones you have changed?

Comment: Just the ones I have changed.

Comment: Ok, let me know if my answer makes sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two ways you can save your data on your Ag-Grid.

1) Get all data and send everything to the backend.

2) Get only the rows which you have changed, and send these rows to the backend. If you want to listen to specific changes to a particular row, you can make use of the `onCellValueChanged` event bindings when defining the ag-grid component on your component template. Basically, whenever the cell has any changes, the entire row will be 'marked' as modified (assign the custom property `modified` to true).

When you need to send the modified rows to your backend, you get all row data, and filter out the rows whereby the 'modified' property is equals to `true`.

Do initialise Ag-grid's params api on your component.

The below code is for #2 since that is what you are seeking.

```
 <ag-grid-angular 
.
.
(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
(cellValueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)"
>
```

and on your component.ts, the onRowValueChanged method will be fired every time you make any changes

```
export class YourComponent {
  private gridApi;
  private gridColumnApi;
   .
   . 
  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
  }

  onCellValueChanged(event) {
    //console.log(event) to test it
    event.data.modified = true;
  }

  saveModifiedRows() {
    const allRowData = [];
    this.gridApi.forEachNode(node => allRowData.push(node.data));
    const modifiedRows = allRowData.filter(row => row['modified']);
    // add API call to save modified rows

  }
```