# ag-grid edit data, then save updated data and send to database

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a empty ag grid table on Angular prepared for user to key in their data. I want to have a button and when user click it, the new data will be saved and then sent to external database.

I have tried way in this answer. [Ag-Grid edit data and sending to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536511/ag-grid-edit-data-and-sending-to-server)

Here's my code.

```
 export class MyComponent {
 gridOptions: GridOptions;
 private gridApi;
 private gridColumnApi;
   .
   . 
constructor(...) {

  this.gridOptions = {
      enableRangeSelection: true,
      columnDefs: [
        {field: 'Id', headerName: 'ID', editable: true },
        {field: 'Address', headerName: 'Address', editable: true },
      ],
      rowData: [
        {Id: '', Address: ''}, ...,{Id: '', Address: ''},
      ],


      onCellValueChanged: function(event)  {
          console.log(event); // access the entire event object
          console.log(event.data); // access and print the updated row data
          const gridData = this.getAllData();   
       },

   }; 

}


getAllData() {
  let rowData = [];
  this.gridApi.forEachNode(node => rowData.push(node.data));
  return rowData;  
}

onGridReady(params) {
  this.gridApi = params.api;
  this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
}
```

```
 <ag-grid-angular 
.
.
(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
[gridOptions]="gridOptions"
>

<button type="button" (click)="getAllData()" class="btn btn-primary">
<span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i></span> Upload To Database </button>
```

After I changed cell value, it threw this error:

**TypeError: this.getAllData is not a function at object.onCellValueChanged.**

How should I solve this?

Comment: What does happen if you comment the entire code in getAllData function and logged some message to guarantee it isn't something else

Comment: I think I might have made a mistake on the example. It should be `onRowValueChanged(event) {...}`.

Comment: Can you try this instead? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55466306/10959940

Answer (score 0):

The context of `this` inside of `gridOptions` is the grid and not your component. In order to call a method on the component from the grid you can either save a reference to the component's `this` and use the reference to call the method on your component:

```
constructor() {
  const self = this;

  this.gridOptions = {
    ...

    onCellValueChanged: function(event)  {
      const gridData = self.getAllData();
    },
  };
}
```

or you can use an arrow function instead:

```
constructor() {  
  this.gridOptions = {
    ...

    onCellValueChanged: (event) => {
      const gridData = this.getAllData();
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a scope issue inside `onCellValueChanged`.

You could simplify this by taking the function out similar to `getAllData()`-

```
  onCellValueChanged() {
      console.log(event); // access the entire event object
      console.log(event.data); // access and print the updated row data
      const gridData = this.getAllData();   
   },
```

And then in gridOptions, define :

```
onCellValueChanged : this.onCellValueChanged
```